# making XML nodes dynamically

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, xml

I am calling an API and have to send a xml request in C# with data in different nodes. How can make xml dynamically and with nodes in incremental naming.

For example

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<addCustomer>
    <FirstName_1>ABC</FirstName_1>
    <LastName_1>DEF</LastName_1>
    <FirstName_2>GSH</FirstName_2>
    <LastName_2>ADSF</LastName_2>
</addCustomer>
```

The problem is making xml nodes with incremental names like FirstName_1,FirstName_2,FirstName_3 and so on.

Comment: Just curious, why you have to do this?

Comment: That's a terrible convention. If you can, try to change the structure of the XML. In any case, the answer to your question is to use an XML library, like LINQ to XML.

Comment: I understand this is not the correct approach but we are integrating the 3rd party API and they required us to send data in this convention.Node number can increase upto 200 like FirstName_1 to FirstName_200

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the simplest solution would be the best here:

Assuming you have a collection of Customer objects called Customers...

```
StringBuilder xmlForApi = new StringBuilder();
int customerCounter = 1;
foreach(Customer c in Customers)
{
    xmlForApi.AppendFormat("<FirstName_{0}>{1}</FirstName_{0}><LastName_{0}>{2}</LastName_{0}>", customerCounter, c.FirstName, c.LastName)
    customerCounter++;
}
```

Comment: I would just like to note that if you were to add the name `Mi|<e` this would break unless you properly encoded the values.

Comment: @gunr2171. You are 100% correct. I hate losing reputation, but, taking your comment under consideration, your answer should have been the accepted one. I'll go ahead and do the next best thing and upvote your answer.

Answer (score 2):

Would a customer have more than one FirstName and more than one LastName?  If each FirstName and LastName pairs represent a different customer then your xml should look something like....

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<AddCustomers>
     <Customer>
          <FirstName>ABC</FirstName>
          <LastName>DEF</LastName>
     </Customer>
     <Customer>
          <FirstName>GSH</FirstName>
          <LastName>ASDF</LastName>
     </Customer>
</AddCustomers>
```

If you absolutely have to do it the way that you did it in your example, I do not see any way to do this except just using a string_builder and create it yourself within a for loop while incrementing your integer to add to the end of each First and last name attributes.  This is not really how xml is supposed to work.

Comment: An XmlWriter would do it pretty fine, and if ABC contains an XML construct such as a '<' or a '&' you end up with invalid XML... Seriously, don't use a stringbuilder for creating your XML.

Answer (score 2):

I know your pain; having to deal with 3rd party APIs can be big pain.

Instead of using `StringBuilder` you can use `XElement`.

```
public void AddCustomerInfo(string firstName, string lastName, int index, XElement root)
{
    XElement firstNameInfo = new XElement("FirstName_" + index);
    firstNameInfo.Value = firstName;

    XElement lastNameInfo = new XElement("LastName_" + index);
    lastNameInfo.Value = lastName;

    root.Add(firstNameInfo);
    root.Add(lastNameInfo);
}
```

Then call the function as the following:

```
XElement rootElement = new XElement("addCustomer");
AddCustomerInfo("ABC", "DEF", 1, rootElement);
```

Put that line inside a loop and you're all set.

Comment: Seeing that the OP is creating "non-standard" XML, I am not sure the overhead of using XElement is giving the OP any benefit.

Comment: While I agree that it's non-standard, it still legal XML. There is an option of using in-memory XML building or StringBuilder. The answer is "is the overhead worth it?"

Comment: For pure academic purposes, I wonder which would use the least number of resources?

Comment: Yes it's worth it. There's a lot of stupid things you can do in XML that XElement will protect you of. As alternative you can as well use XmlDocument or XmlWriter if you really don't want too much overhead. Either way using a StringBuilder or a StringWriter is the worst possible solution, because it will eventually bite you in the ....